# Упало fps при отрисовке на PictureBox

Tags: c#

Я ещё новичок, так что строго не судите. Делал на заставку анимацию "падающие символы", примерно как в матрице, получилось, но потом потребовалось наложить картинку, после чего fps снизилось до нельзя. Помогите исправить.

[рабочая версия](https://yadi.sk/d/O1kzaat4ZLDk4)
[не рабочая версия](https://yadi.sk/d/OQsO6vjJZLDk8)

Answer (score 2):

Вы каждый раз перерисовываете картинку в цикле да еще и с альфа-каналом, попробуйте разнести картинку и матрицу по разным контролам... ну это если навскидку.... или попробуйте рисовать картинку в памяти, а потом выводить ее на экран